# How to return HttpClient response body from a request?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient, angular-resolver

I have a component that relies on an API response for its content. I have set up the resolver but it still returns before my data is ready.

How can I make my `pull_categories()` function wait until the response body is received and then return? Rather than returning an empty object because it won't wait or even call it in my case below.

---

service.ts

```js
private _categories = [];

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

pull_categories() {
    this.http.post('https://myapi.com/something', null)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this._categories = data['response'];
            return this._categories;
        }
    );
}
```

---

component.ts

```js
categories = [];

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(
        (data: Data) => {
            this.categories = data.categories;
        }
    );
}
```

---

resolver.ts

```js
constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return this.categoriesService.pull_categories();
}
```

---

app-routing.module.ts

```js
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {categories: CategoriesResolverService}
}
```

Comment: You can use Angular route guards to wait until the data is loaded before going to that page.

Comment: @PavanBahuguni That's what i'm trying to do but not working so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, in service.ts you don't need to subscribe, You should subscribe where you want to actually consume the data. `subscribe` method returns `Subscription`, not the response from the http api.

You can update your service method as

```
pull_categories(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://myapi.com/something', null);
}
```

`pull_categories` method will return immediately with an `Observable`, when you subscribe on it in your component (or anywhere), http call will be executed and response will be returned in your `subscribe` section.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning a `Subscription` from your service (and thus your resolver), instead of returning an Observable. Don't subscribe in services. And specify return values, to avoid shooting yourself in the foot:

```
getCategories(): Observable<Array<Category>> {
  return this.http.get<Something>('https://myapi.com/something').pipe(
    map(something => something.response)
  );
}
```

Note

- the respect for naming conventions
- the usage of GET to... get data, instead of POST
- that the method defines what it actually returns
- the usage of the generic overload of the HttpClient.get() method, which allows specifying the expected type of the response body
- that having an instance fields in the service is wrong (and unnecessary).

Read the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) guide, and the [RxJS](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) quide.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed help, i will surely note these down.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get data from your backend is rather than subscribing to the data, you may also return back a promise and then use async await in your component

```js
pull_categories(): any {
    return this.http.post('https://myapi.com/something', null).toPromise();
}
```

This will return back a promise to your component where you can also use in the following way:

```js
async getCategories() {
  try {
    const categories = await this.service.pull_categories();
  } catch (e) {

  }
}
```